# how to set gridview animation for specific child android

Tags: android, animation, gridview

I have gridview of images and I need to start fade in animation from only 4th image.

```
 GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 5.0f);

    animation.setDuration(2000);

    set.addAnimation(animation);

    LayoutAnimationController controller = new                LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);

    gridView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

with above code I can animate irrespective of all childView .**I need to start animate from only 4th child** please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just code like below... in your `getView()` method

```
if (position == 0) {
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.frame);
                mAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) v.getBackground();
                v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (mAnimation != null)
                            mAnimation .start();
                    }
                }, 100);
            }else{

            }
```

Comment: it is very kind of you.This is what i am expected.But i need to show animation one by one now am getting all at once after my specified child please help.

Comment: make else part in that.

Comment: can i know what logic i have to apply in else part? thanks in advance.

Comment: if I apply inside getView() the all view will populating at once. I need One by one after my specified child.

Comment: Can anyone explain this?